# Tengo un problema: La declaración de importación está en conflicto con la declaración local de "$".ts(2440)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando en Angular y resulta que estoy tratando de resolver un problema con el template de sidebar de adminlte, donde uno de los botones tiene un conflicto que me daña la arquitectura que tengo en las ruta, por ejemplo cuando un usuario inicia sesión, se redirige directamente a la ruta de dashboard y alli tengo un sidebar con un menu desplegable, entonces cuando se le da click a ese botón pues redirecciona al usuario de nuevo al login automáticamente y esto no puede pasar. He visto que este es un problema que presenta adminlte en su tempalte con las rutas ya que tiene un archivo Js que contiene el sidebar y este tiene un servicio llamado data-widget="treeview" que demora en construir y crear este elemento y como sabemos Angular es asincrono y se mantiene construyendo y destruyendo elementos, entonces buscando me encontré con que para solucionarlo, debo crear el siguiente código:

**primero importar el Jquery:**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

**Depues dentro del ngOnInit() poner este codigo en donde se construye el servicio de treewiew y se inicializa:**

```
$('[data-widget="treeview"]').Treevieww('init');
```

**Luego creamos este otro metodo:**

```
  //Este método ira como evento (click) en el boton de cerrar sesion y se encargara de sacarnos del servicio data-widget="treeview", servirá para sacar de la sesión al usuario y destruir todo el servicio del data-widget       
        logout(){
                    //Entonces para cuando se destruya el servicio:
                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');//Acá le decimos que nos redireccione directamente al login
}
```

Y por ultimo para que en el código que construye el servicio en el ngOnInit() no tenga ningún problema debemos declarar la variable del Jquery debajo de los import de este mismo componente:

```
declare var $:any;
```

El problema aquí es que en el import del Jquery osea este `import * as $ from 'jquery';` la variable `$` se me marca un error con el siguiente mensaje:

```
La declaración de importación está en conflicto con la declaración local de "$".ts(2440)
```

Esta es una captura para más completa para agregar algo de más detalle:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error. Ya que si no declaro allí la variable `declare var $:any;`, al momento de construir el servicio que equivale a que Angular construya de nuevo ese elemento pues no pasa y cuando cargo la pagina, el botón de despliegue donde tengo el menú desaparece.

**Vision general:** El sentido que tiene de crear ese código es que con ello estamos controlando y asegurando la construcción de ese servicio (prácticamente de ese elemento boton desplegable) en el metodo ngOnInit() y con el método "logout()" lo estamos destruyendo.

Pdt: En consola estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:
vendor.js:26617

```
   ERROR TypeError: $(...).Treevieww is not a function
at SidebarComponent.ngOnInit (main.js:1380:39)
at callHook (vendor.js:22674:22)
at callHooks (vendor.js:22643:17)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (vendor.js:22594:9)
at refreshView (vendor.js:29631:21)
at refreshComponent (vendor.js:30792:13)
at refreshChildComponents (vendor.js:29412:9)
at refreshView (vendor.js:29666:13)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (vendor.js:30746:17)
at refreshView (vendor.js:29640:9)
```

Comment: ¿Probaste `import $ from 'jquery';` sin la línea `declare var $:any;`? Así es como lo recomiendan en la [documentación de npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#:~:text=import%20%24%20from%20%22jquery%22%3B).

Comment: No olvides instalar el tipado para typescript `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

Comment: Es mejor usar una plantilla hecha para Angular y que no lleve el Jquery https://akveo.github.io/ngx-admin/

Comment: y esto?  **Treevieww**, existe con dos ww al final?

Comment: @Jaime, lo acabo de solucionar, tenia dos errores por corregir, el metodo Treeview, lo tenia con dos veces w en el método ngOnInit y también tuve que eliminar el import y solo dejar  "declare var $:any;". De esa forma, el componente del menu ya no me desaparece cuando cuargo la pagina y tampoco me manda el error:  "ERROR TypeError: $(...).Treevieww is not a function". Gracias brother de todas formas

Comment: @Lobos no la conocía :D y si estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices, gracias por el aporte, sabes si es gratuito?

Comment: @DEVX75, ya lo solucione jeje, tenia mal escrito ese método y también solo deje la linea donde esta el declare y elimine el import, de esa forma se arreglo el problema, gracias brother.